# What happens to the potential difference and charge of a capacitor with dielectric if a battery is disconnected?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, dielectric

if I have a capacitor connected to a battery of 12V and it has 3C of charge and I add a dielectric let's say $q$ would increase to 6C and $ΔV$ would remain constant. Now I'll disconnect the battery, keeping the dielectric in place, will q remain 6C and ΔV remain 12V?

Answer (score 0):

Why should anything change as there is no conducting path between the two plates?
The "extra" energy stored in the dielectric cannot change unless the dielectric is imperfect and there is a "leakage" current which discharges the capacitor.
The storage capacity of the dielectric is shown in this video, [MIT Physics Demo -- Dissectible Capacitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ckpQW9sdUg). A Leyden jars is a type of capacitor,